# Integrating a function's gradient

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Given the gradient of a function, how do you find the function itself?

For a scalar-valued function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, the gradient of $f$, denoted $\nabla f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, is defined as

$\nabla f(x)_i := \frac{\delta f(x)}{\delta x_i}, \quad i=1,\ldots,n.$

For example, for $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $b,x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, the gradient of the function

$f(x) := \frac{1}{2} (Ax-b)^T(Ax-b)$

is

$\nabla f(x) = (Ax-b)^T A.$

Now suppose we are told that the gradient of a scalar-valued function $g$ is

$\nabla g(x) = (Ax-b)^T D$

for some diagonal matrix $D \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

**Is there a nice closed-form expression for $g(x)$?**

These two threads ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596450/how-would-i-undo-a-gradient-function), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/834607/is-it-possible-to-reverse-a-gradient-vec-nabla-operation)) seem to use guess-and-check. We tried looking at function of the form

$g(x) := \frac{1}{2} (Ax-b)^T W (Ax-b)$

for various weighting matrices $W$, but no dice.

Comment: It's not even true that a $g$ must exist. Start by solving the ODE for the first component, then go down the second and so on and so on. You will easily see that lots of relations must hold for a $g$ to exist

Comment: I’d hardly call the method in the accepted answer to the second question you cite “guess and check.” It’s precisely the method sketched out in the previous comment.

Comment: The inverse gradient problem is not solvable in general. You can construct many gradients when it is impossible to find g. You can still try to minimize the error in some sense, though.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice closed form expression for $g(x)$ **if it exists**. Assuming it does, the path integration is quite straightforward.
\begin{multline}
g(x) = \int\nabla g(x)\cdot d\mathbf{x} = \int (\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{b})^T\mathbf{D}d\mathbf{x} = \int \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{D}d\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{D}\int d\mathbf{x}
\\?= \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{D}\mathbf{x} -\mathbf{b}^T\mathbf{D}\mathbf{x} = \left(\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{b}\right)^T\mathbf{D}\mathbf{x}
\end{multline}

However, the equality with the ? in front of it is not, in general, true. What condition on $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{D}$ is needed to make it true?

Comment: I believe the condition is that $A^TD$ is symmetric. If that doesn't hold, does this mean that $g(x)$ doesn't exist?

Comment: Easier: Transpose and just look at $DA$. Yes, you need $DA$ to be symmetric. You want to think about the necessary condition (in order for a vector field to be a gradient, it must satisfy the equality of mixed-partials condition): You need $\partial f_i/\partial x_j = \partial f_j/\partial x_i$ for all $i,j$. In all of $\Bbb R^n$, this condition is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer... Just to give a simple example why it is not always solvable. Imagine a function $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$.

Let us prescribe any non-closed (importante!) contour of gradient orthogonal to the direction of the contour with $\nabla g = \|\nabla g\|\hat n$. Now let every other point in the plane have $\nabla g = 0$

What happens at the end points of this contour?

We can walk (integrate) around it along lines consisting of points of gradient 0. Along these lines the function value must not change because both partial differentials are 0. But yet if we walk (integrate) across the contour the function value is prescribed to change.

It becomes an impossible situation.

**Example** : Consider the function $$x,y \to f = \cases{1, x^2+y^2 < 0.5\\0,x^2+y^2 \geq 0.5}\\ x,y \in \mathbb R^2$$ and its gradient with color coded direction:

[image] [image]

Example if we set the negative half-plane (y<0) of the gradient to $0$ and try to solve with a numerical solver, optimizing $$\min_f\|(\nabla f) - g_0\|_2^2$$, where $g_0$ is the truncated gradient field preserved only for positive y:s as explained above :

[image]  [image]

You can't first walk up a hill and then find some path to walk around the hill getting back to the place of the lower altitude without descending anywhere along the way. If a map says that you can then that map does not describe our world.